# Singular or plural scope names in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a question in my head.

Is there any disadvantage to using singular or plurial in names for scope ?
I found nothing on the question. Sometimes I put in the plural to help me understand the real scope without following convention.

There's a convetion?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of one.  I use whatever "reads well."  If the scope is filtering there results, then plural seems to read the best -- `User.admin` vs `User.admins`.  But not all the time.  `Event.on_date(Time.now)` wouldn't make sense as a plural.  But then again I'd really rather that was `Events.on_date...` but I can't do that either.

So for me... whatever reads the best while writing the code is probably the right way to go.

Comment: I think so too. I wanted to have a another opinions for know  practices of another developer.